# Is there a way to convert a WEBGL model into a system of points?

Tags: javascript, matrix, multidimensional-array, 3d, webgl

I have an idea to make a 3D model of a head with shoulders. I'm trying to figure out a way to model this such that the shape of the head is formed by tiny spheres (with space between them). These tiny spheres will be mapped across the contours of the face and head creating the image of a human.

This is about the closest example I can think of...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DX3qLIwHoUo (1:58, The Matrix Revolution, *SPOILER*). In this case, the face is formed out of millions of dots, and its more like a swarm. But I would like this model to be comprised only a few hundred dots with space between them so you can kind of see through to the other side.

I'm using "Lee" from the WEBGL server for my human template.

My question is  - How do I represent Lee as a collection black points rather than as a single piece?

And is there some more general solution that could be implimented to convert any Webgl shape to this style?

Thanks for reading, any advice is appreciated

Comment: draw your geometry using [`POINT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml) mode?

Comment: what is "Lee" from the WEBGL server? I didn't know there was something called "the WEBGL server" and I certainly have no idea what "Lee" is

Comment: MeshLab can distribute random points along given mesh surface. (eg Poisson Disk Sampling). Otherwise, many decent 3D soft can do that.

Comment: When you're loading your model then instead of creating triangles create a sphere or billboard at every mesh vertex.